# Replace special characters or special characters followed by space

Tags: c#, regex, text

I have this particular string:

```
Administrationsomkostninger                           I              -2.889         - r0.l l0
```

I would like to replace these characters:r,l and i with 1. 
I use this expression:

```
([(t|r|l|i|)])
```

That gives me this string:

```
Adm1n1s11a11onsomkos1n1nge1                           1              -2.889         - 10.1 10
```

Now i want to replace the all digits that contains a digit followed + a whitespace

so in this case only  `- 10.1 10` gets converted to `-10.110`

Comment: Use Regex? It is perfect for all situations where you want to search strings for characters.

Comment: How do you distinguish between the whitespace in the middle (next to the 1) and the ones you apparently do want to delete?

Comment: @Reality-Torrent: This is exactly what question is about???

Comment: @MrLister: That's my problem. The only way I see it is to create a regex(which I need help to) to match on a digit followed by a space and digit.

Comment: What is the final output you seek for the current example string?

Comment: Adm1n1s11a11onsomkos1n1nge1                           1              -2.889         - 10.110

Comment: Something like [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5cd)%5cp%7bZs%7d%2b(%5cd)&i=Adm1n1s11a11onsomkos1n1nge1+++++++++++++++++++++++++++1++++++++++++++-2.889+++++++++-+10.1+10+&r=%241%242)? However, I get `Adm1n1s11a11onsomkos1n1nge11              -2.889         - 10.110` (with multiple space, see *Context* tab on regexstorm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
            string input = "Administrationsomkostninger                           I              -2.889         - r0.l l0";
            string pattern = @"(?'spaces'\s){2,}";
            string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, " ");
​
```

Comment: I found the solution . By using multiple regex expression solved the issue. Thanks.